# React Native: Creating custom tabs with animation

Tags: react-native

I have this use case which is a bit confusing compared to the norm , and Im not sure how to structure it. I have a screen (tabs) with 4 tabs .

The thing is that the contents of each tab (their screens) are actually in One big page, when scrolling down the page and it reaches the contents of Tab2 ,  the tab should change too to Tab2 (its not actually a screen change) .

Now initially I have used `react-navigation` and it's `tab navigator`. But here Im not sure if this should use tab navigator. The questions that arise to me (from the top of my head):

Q1) If we wrap the components (each tab's screen) in a parent one. How do we go about detecting where the scroll reached! (or something that notifies we are viewing contents of tab2 and so on...)

Q2) How can I handle the animation of the tabs (especially the line under them as shown in the image) to transition back and forth?

Q3) Is there a better way to do this! (better than my initial thoughts above)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Q1. You must use the `TabNavigator` to avoid the problem as you asking in Q1. So you don't need to worry about the Scroll.

Q2. I recommend using `StyleSheet`, create a CSS style for line bar then maybe you just need to call a function to set the CSS of current tab or use the `navigation options`.

Q3. `TabNavigator` is a good option here and it belongs to `react-navigation`.

[TabNavigator](https://github.com/pkhighfile/UdaciCards/blob/master/utils/appTabs.js)

[Animation example with custom function](https://github.com/pkhighfile/UdaciCards/blob/master/components/QuizView.js)

---

**--- Update ------**
I have created an example project for you to solve the problem, I'm not sure if you're doing the same.

1. Check the Scroll.js, I added a function Callme that changes tabs when scroll reaches to end.
2. To detect the Scroll reaches to end or not, I have used the isCloseToBottom from another StackOverflow answer.

Follow the following link to Github project.

[Change-Tabs-When-Scroll-End](https://github.com/pkhighfile/Change-Tabs-When-Scroll-End-)

Thanks

_Pradeep

Comment: But tab navigator changes tabs when we swipe from one screen to another, how would it help me to detect which section tab screen I am currently viewing when scrolling. (this is single screen page with tabbar and their screens, there are no saperate screens for each tab)

Comment: If I understand correctly that you can try following method but I never get the chance to use this.

You can export each section as it's on your single page, then use in TabNavigator as a screen. 

I hope you visited the official doc, https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab

Is possible for you to share your screen page codes, so I understand well and suggest.

Comment: I don't think you understood tab navigator well. `TabNavigator(routeConfig, tabBarConfig)` the route config consists tabs screens. to navigate between the screens, you have to swipe. I don't see how I can put all screens of the tabs in one page using tab navigator

Comment: I think you still not visited my project https://github.com/pkhighfile/UdaciCards/blob/master/utils/appTabs.js

Once you assign all screen or section to TabNavigator then you have to use the StackNavigator to add all tabs in one page in my case I set them on the homepage.

Comment: let me get this straight. you have a `tabNavigator` : DeckList and AddDeck , which in turn called `Tabs` and this Tabs is in `stackNavigator` in Home Page. Now in your `HomePage` you have Tabs. So far all good. now my question is : How do you navigate between `Screen DeckList` and `Screen AddDeck` ?? I assume by swiping from one tab to another, isn't that right ?

Comment: Yes, It's right,  You can navigate between swiping or press on tab name itself.

Comment: Are you familiar with Scroll View or Scrollable- tab-view 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-scrollable-tab-view,

Comment: I'm creating an example for you, let you know once I have done